# python-read file names and build a namelist

Tags: python

I want to make a name list and store all the names in four folders. I build

```
namelist = {1:[], 2:[], 3:[], 4:[]}
```

In the method, I write

```
for file_name in sorted(os.listdir(full_subdir_name)):
    full_file_name = os.path.join(full_subdir_name,file_name)
    #namelist[level] += blabla...
```

I want to add the names from the first folder into namelist[1], from the second folder to namelist[2]. I don't know how I can add all the names in different levels to it. Thx!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you changing the value of `full_subdir_name` sometimes? Is that what determines what `level` should be?

Comment: full_subdir_name is the path of the folder that contains all the four folders I want. it does not change

Comment: That also confuses me. My apologies. In that case, won't the elements returned to you from `os.listdir(full_subdir_name)` be the names of the folders, and not the names of their content files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not totally sure this is what you are getting at with your question above. But it seems that first, you want to use `enumerate()` to allow you to keep the index *and* name of the four folders. But then, I think you will actually need an additional for-loop, based on your comments above, to actually append all of the contents for each of the files within each sub-folder. The following should do the trick.

Also note that your dictionary keys start with `1`, so you need to account for the fact that the enumerate index starts with 0.

```
# Here, enumerate gives back the index and element.
for i,file_name in enumerate(sorted(os.listdir(full_subdir_name))):
    full_file_name = os.path.join(full_subdir_name,file_name)

    # Here, 'elem' will be the strings naming the actual
    # files inside of the folders.

    for elem in sorted(os.listdir(full_file_name)):
        # Here I am assuming you don't want to append the full path,
        # but you can easily change what to append by adding the
        # whole current file path: os.path.join(full_file_name, elem)

        namelist[i+1].append(elem)
```